# Infragistics igCombo making input box smaller?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, infragistics, ignite-ui

I am currently showing 3 columns on my dropdown which needs to be wide, but do not need a big input field for the igCombo, as I need to squeeze a lot more fields onto my form.  The default input field width=360px is too large.   How to modify the input field to be smaller, without affecting the dropdown size.  If I change the width, it also seems to change the dropdown width as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the drop down container width through the [dropDownWidth](http://help.infragistics.com/jQuery/2014.1/ui.igcombo#options:dropDownWidth) option. So change the width of the `igCombo` and then set the `dropDownWidth` to the amount that you want it to be:

```
$(".selector").igCombo({
    width: 200,
    dropDownWidth: 360
});
```